# jQuery slider with both navigation and sub navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

At the moment I have a slider that works by using arrows and dots for navigation. However, I want to add an additional component to the right of the slider which serves as multi-page directory for the slider to choose from by having numbered pages that hold an additional array of images in each respective number of the page.

I'm having trouble linking the "01" page to there each individual array of images. Therefore a click on "01", "02", "03" will be a different collection of an array of images into the slider. Rather the way I have it right now which just cycles through sample images.

Ive added a demo http://jsfiddle.net/R77EB/3000/ to hopefully clarify anything that is confusing, however the jsfiddle does not have the dot navigation operating because I cant seem to get it work on the jsfiddle, but it works fine serperately in my text edit software.

What would be the most efficient method to achieve this effect?

Thanks. 
[image: Multiple Navigation]

**HTML**

```
<div id="rectangle">
  <div class="nav">
    <ul>
       <li class="first"><a href="#">01</a></li>
       <li class="second"><a href="#">02</a></li>
       <li class="third"><a href="#">03</a></li>
    </ul>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="image-box">
  <img class="p-first" src="img/SampleImage.png" width="300" height="200">
  <img class="p-first" src="img/SampleImage.png" width="300" height="200">
  <img class="p-first" src="img/SampleImage.png" width="300" height="200">
</div>

<div class="image-box">
  <img class="p-second" src="img/SampleImage.png" width="300" height="200">
  <img class="p-second" src="img/SampleImage.png" width="300" height="200">
  <img class="p-second" src="img/SampleImage.png" width="300" height="200">
</div>

<div class="image-box">
  <img class="p-third" src="img/SampleImage.png" width="300" height="200">
  <img class="p-third" src="img/SampleImage.png" width="300" height="200">
  <img class="p-third" src="img/SampleImage.png" width="300" height="200">
</div>


<nav class="slider-nav">
  <div class="nav-list">
    <div class="nav-label">Digital</div>
      <div class="nav-dot select"></div>
         <div class="nav-dot"></div>
         <div class="nav-dot"></div>
         <div class="nav-dot"></div>
</div>
<div class="nav-spacing"></div>
   <div class="nav-list">
      div class="nav-label">Physical</div>
        <div class="nav-dot select"></div>
        <div class="nav-dot"></div>
        <div class="nav-dot"></div>
        <div class="nav-dot"></div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**jQuery**

```
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".p-first, .p-second, .p-third").hide();
    });


    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".first").click(function () {
            $(".p-first").toggle();
        });
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".second").click(function () {
            $(".p-second").toggle();
        });
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".third").click(function () {
            $(".p-third").toggle();
        });
    });
```

**CSS**

```
   #rectangle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 226px;
  left: 691px;
  height: 561px;
  width: 996px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  opacity: .5;
}

.nav {
  position: relative;
  top: 25px;
  left: 1006px;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 2px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.image-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 226px;
  left: 691px;
}

.slider-nav {
  position: relative;
  top: 800px;
  left: 800px;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -webkit-align-content: stretch;
  -webkit-align-items: stretch;
}

.nav-list {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none
}

.nav-label {
  margin-left: 5px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 2px;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: gray;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-family: 'Brandon Grotesque', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 10px;
}

.nav-spacing {
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
  width: 1px;
  height: 26px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background-color: #d8d8d8;
}

.nav-dot {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin-right: 3px;
  margin-left: 3px;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #E6E7E8;
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out
}

.nav-dot.select {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.nav-dot:hover {
  border: 1px solid #202020;
}
```

Comment: have you tried this link? http://www.slidesjs.com/

Is pretty easy to setup

Comment: The slider I have works, I just want to add additional functionality. Basically Im building a portfolio site, therefore I will have a lot of images. I want to be able to categorize the images into separate pages rather then display them all at once in a single slider.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to get a reply here at stack overflow. But I did get some help from another forum in order to solve the problem, here is where you can read the thread here http://www.codingforums.com/javascript-frameworks/377190-jquery-slider-both-navigation-sub-navigation.html

**Html**

```
<body>
<div class="my-slider" id="group1">
    <ul>
        <li><img class="img-box" src="img/SampleImage.png"></li>
        <li><img class="img-box" src="img/SampleImage.png"></li>
        <li><img class="img-box" src="img/SampleImage.png"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="my-slider" id="group2">
    <ul>
        <li><img class="img-box" src="img/SampleImage.png"></li>
        <li><img class="img-box" src="img/SampleImage.png"></li>
        <li><img class="img-box" src="img/SampleImage.png"></li>
        <li><img class="img-box" src="img/SampleImage.png"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="my-slider" id="group3">
    <ul>
        <li><img class="img-box" src="img/SampleImage.png"></li>
        <li><img class="img-box" src="img/SampleImage.png"></li>
        <li><img class="img-box" src="img/SampleImage.png"></li>
        <li><img class="img-box" src="img/SampleImage.png"></li>
        <li><img class="img-box" src="img/SampleImage.png"></li>
    </ul>
</div>


<nav class="nav-wrapper">
   <div class="first"><a data-id="group1" class="grpsel initial" href="#">01</a></div>
   <div class="second"><a data-id="group2" class="grpsel" href="#">02</a>     </div>
   <div class="third"><a data-id="group3" class="grpsel" href="#">03</a>   </div>
</nav>
</body>
```

**jQuery**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $('.my-slider').unslider();
        $(".grpsel").on("click", function () {
            var grp = $(this).attr("data-id");
            $(".unslider").hide();
            $("#" + grp).parent().show();
        })
        $("a.initial").click();
    });
```

**CSS**

```
      body {
  }

  .my-slider {
      position: absolute;
      top: 226px;
      left: 691px;
      height: 561px;
      width: 996px;
      opacity: .5;
  }

  .img-box {
      max-height: 561px;
      max-width: 996px;
  }

  a {
      text-decoration: none;
  }

  .nav-wrapper {
      position: absolute;
      top: 250px;
      right: 200px;
  }

  .first,
  .second,
  .third {
      padding-bottom: 5px;
  }
```